# Como criar um Menu estilo Minecraft no Projeto do Ulixava?

Tags: java, menu

Como eu crio um Menu estilo Minecraft para meu jogo em Java?

Eu assisti os 3 episódios da série: How to make a 2d minecraft plataformer in java, e tenho o jogo, mas eu queria criar um menu para ele, porém não faço ideia de como.

link da serie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tge-9Ovj3Tc

Comment: Atenção!!!! eu não botei mais tags porque tava dizendo que eu tinha que ter mais Reputação!! não sei porque tem umonte de gente que fica botando Negativo para minhas perguntas, mais e porque não tenho reputação para por outras tags!!!!! deu para entender??

Comment: @Math Perdão, acabei sugerindo uma edição quase ao mesmo tempo que a sua foi feita.

Comment: @GWER sem problemas. Essas coisas acontecem de vez em quando ;)

Comment: alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: @LunarD12 se você recebeu votos negativos foi por algum motivo, que não deve se tratar apenas das tags. Estes links podem te ajudar a adequar suas perguntas e não receber mais estes votos: 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Tinha colocado um link errado, mas já editei e coloquei o certo. Dá uma olhadinha aí, e bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português ;)